# how to implement a conditional angular repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Fairly new to angular so bear with me. I have an angular page that has the following code in it:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
//do stuff
</div>
```

Now, I want to add tabs on the top of the page. Then, when a user clicks on the tabs it will change some model variable "Tab". Depending on the tab, I want the page to change. The issue is that the //do stuff does not need to change very much. However I do need to loop through a different set of items (of a slightly different type, so I can't just filter some master list) depending on the tab. Is there any way to do a ng-repeat where the list depends on the tab?

Edit: I had an idea to something like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items{{Tab}}">
    //do stuff
    </div>
```

The idea is that angular will evaluate the items{{Tab}} and then call the appropriate list. Somehow this is not working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into angular routes and loading your data from the controller/service methods.  This will allow the client to set the view, and will get the data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am indeed loading my data by controller methods.

Comment: Then use ng-Route to configure the views.  You pass the directive the views you want to use and their respective controllers, and the view will be correctly rendered with appropriate data by the route directive.

Comment: Ok thanks. This was actually really helpful. I didn't know about routes at all until now. I started reading up on them. They look like they will be really helpful.

Comment: By using routes, you can completely bypass all server-side page rendering, allowing you to make your server essentially just a rest service.  It's a really nice feature of angular.

Comment: What do you mean by a "rest service"?

Comment: Basically, it means the server only returns responses, not rendered pages, e.g. JSON responses to ajax calls, but no server resources, like jsps are returned